# reading tcp packets out of order

Tags: tcp, network-programming

Web games are forced to use tcp.
But with real time constraints tcp head of line blocking behavior is absurd **when you don't care about old packets**.

While I'm aware that there's definitely nothing that we can do on the client side, I'm wondering if there is a solution on the server side.

Indeed, on the server you get packets in order and miserably wait if misbehaving packet t+42 has been lost even though packets t+43, t+44 **can already be nicely waiting in your receive buffer**.

Since we are talking about local data, technically it *should* be possible to retrieve it..

So does anyone have an idea on how to perform that feat?
How to save this precious data from these pesky kernel space daemons?

Comment: Perhaps your target platform (the "web") is the wrong choice here? Or haven't searched for solutions hard enough ([this framework](https://github.com/networkprotocol/netcode.io) came (indirectly) up high in a search for `javascript web send udp packets`).

Comment: I took the liberty to clean up your tags a bit. Half of them didn't belong here, as should be obvious from reading their description.

Comment: Oh, btw: Your assumption that "Web games are forced to use tcp" may be flawed already. What keeps you from using UDP or SCTP or other protocols?

Comment: Thank you Ulrich.
I tried WebRTC data channels which are not designed for games and difficult to use. netcode.io uses a browser specific plugin.
So the only options are http 1/2 and websockets (which I'm using).

Comment: The I would argue that either your requirements (forcing you to the wrong target platform) are flawed, or your design is. If you're forced to use the "web" target platform, then you have to work with the possible limitations inherent in that platform, which includes TCP only.

Comment: That might very well be true, I'm also targeting desktop and mobile platforms using UDP.
I already have a simple working websocket solution, but was just considering how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TCP guarantees that the data arrives in order and re-transmits lost packets.` [TCP Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)

Given this, there is only one way to achieve the results you want given your stated constraints, and that is to hack the TCP protocol at the server side (assuming you cannot control the Client WebSocket behavior). The simplest, relative term, would be to open a raw socket, implement your own simple TCP handshake (Syn-Ack when client Syns), then read and write from the socket managing your own TCP headers. Your custom implementation would need to keep track of received sequence numbers and acknowledge all of those you want the client to forget about.

You might be able to reduce effort by making this program a proxy to your original.

Example of TCP raw socket [here](https://github.com/rbaron/raw_tcp_socket/blob/master/raw_tcp_socket.c).